# Scala: Creating List of Functions from an Import

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm attempting to create a list of functions so that I can map it to a DataFrame, but even after searching around I cannot figure out how to pass a fully qualified function name into a list. Even with what I do have compiling, I'm fairly sure that `math.min` and `math.max` are not what I'm looking for, as the functions I'm actually executing come from the `org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` import.
 
How can I create a list of functions from a specific import?

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// This works - map each function over the DF columns
df.select(df.columns.map(mean): _*).show
df.select(df.columns.map(max): _*).show
df.select(df.columns.map(min): _*).show  

val functions = Array(math.min _, math.max _) // this isn't throwing errors  
/*****************************************************************************/  
// These attempts to create function lists don't work
val functions = Array(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.mean _, math.min _, math.max _) // won't compile  
val functions = Array(_ => org.apache.spark.sql.functions.mean(_), math.min _, math.max _) // doesn't work

// apply each function to the columns and then combine into one dataframe
functions.map(f => df.select(numeric_df.columns.map(f): _*)).reduce(_ union _).show
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a list with constants `a`, `b`, ... , `z`, then you

1. Make sure that the constants are in scope (e.g. by importing them)
2. Put them in the list

Something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{mean, min, max}
val functions: Array[String => Column] = 
  Array(mean(_: String), min(_: String), max(_: String))
```

The explicit type annotations in eta expansions are necessary because the methods `mean`, `min`, `max` are overloaded (there are both `mean(colName: String)` and `mean(c: Column)`).

Those functions have of course nothing whatsoever to do with `math.max` etc., these are spark-sql functions that can be applied to columns.